# Mysql query left join and group concat

Tags: mysql

I wrote mysql query to bring data from mysql

```
SELECT p.TITLE AS `Post Title`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.USERNAME) AS Writers,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.CategoryName) AS Categories
FROM Posts p
JOIN Posts_Writers pw ON pw.PostID = p.PostID
JOIN Users u ON u.USERID = pw.USERID
JOIN Posts_Categories pc ON pc.PostID = p.PostID
JOIN Categories c ON c.Id = pc.CategoryId
GROUP BY p.TITLE


CREATE TABLE Posts (
  `PostID` INTEGER,
  `TITLE` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Posts
  (`PostID`, `TITLE`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'SOME TITLE');

CREATE TABLE Users (
  `USERID` INTEGER,
  `USERNAME` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO Users
  (`USERID`, `USERNAME`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Alaa'),
  ('2', 'John');

CREATE TABLE Posts_Writers (
  id INT auto_increment primary key,
  PostID INT,
  USERID INT
);

INSERT INTO Posts_Writers (PostId, USERID) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2);

CREATE TABLE Categories (
  `Id` INTEGER,
  `CategoryName` VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO Categories
  (`Id`, `CategoryName`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Business'),
  ('2', 'Marketing');

CREATE TABLE Posts_Categories (
  id INT auto_increment primary key,
  PostID INT,
  CategoryID INT
);

INSERT INTO Posts_Categories (PostID, CategoryID) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2);
```

The query is work fine

The problem is:

I bring all categories from mysql by group_concat like this (Business,Marketing)

But let's say that i want to filter results for an category

I want to get results for Business category

I tried to add those conditions

```
WHERE c.CategoryName = 'Business'
```

AND

```
AND c.CategoryName = 'Business'
```

The filters works, and the results as expected

BUT. the problem is the output of categories is only 'Business'

Not Business,Marketing as before

Here is SQLFiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67sGFv3xcERojvypmjdF8/1

I WANT ALWAYS TO GET THE FULL LIST OF CATEGORIES

this is the result i want

```
Business,Marketing
```

Comment: you want always the full list of categories ..in group_concat also if your filter is for one category  .? is not clear  ...so. update your question and show us your expected  result

Comment: Exactly, i want to get the full list of categories, i've updated the question thankyou

Comment: but is not logic ..  if you want filter for a category then this only is retunrned  from the join and one only is use in group_concat  ..  try expalin better ..

Comment: If you have a blog, and i search for posts that tagged by "Love" it will bring me all posts that tagged under "Love" but you can still see all posts with their full list of tags "love" "i" "you"

Answer (score 0):

If you want always  the full list for categories (before filter) the yiu could use the original query as subquery for get the list

```
SELECT p.TITLE AS `Post Title`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.USERNAME) AS Writers,
       t.Categories
FROM Posts p
JOIN Posts_Writers pw ON pw.PostID = p.PostID
JOIN Users u ON u.USERID = pw.USERID
JOIN Posts_Categories pc ON pc.PostID = p.PostID
JOIN Categories c ON c.Id = pc.CategoryId
JOIN (
  SELECT p.TITLE,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.USERNAME) AS Writers,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.CategoryName) AS Categories
  FROM Posts p
  JOIN Posts_Writers pw ON pw.PostID = p.PostID
  JOIN Users u ON u.USERID = pw.USERID
  JOIN Posts_Categories pc ON pc.PostID = p.PostID
  JOIN Categories c ON c.Id = pc.CategoryId
  GROUP BY p.TITLE
) t ON t.title = p.TITLE
GROUP BY p.TITLE, t.Categories
WHERE c.CategoryName = 'Business'
```